# Bands that have split up, then using same band name?

Tags: bands, names

are there any bands that has been split (because of artistic differences or whatever reason) and then after continued playing/releasing albums using the same/similar band name?

Comment: Voting to close as a [list question](http://meta.musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/77/are-list-questions-on-topic).

Comment: Yes. Half the bands from the 70s… including at least one that had 2 incarnations, each with one original member. [The Sweet]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guns 'N Roses essentially fits this bill, as Axl Rose is the only original member who resurrected the band after they broke up.